# SherlockActionBar not showing on 4.2.2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My Sherlock action bar will work on samsung galaxy s2 4.0.3 and emulator 2.1 but not on nexus 10 4.2.2, really can't figure out why.

Here is my related code :

In main activity :

```
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar(); 
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // do stuff with CalendarContract
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(viewIntent, 2);

        break;

    case R.id.add_alarm:
        loadTimer();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlarmReceiverActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PickADayActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>



    <receiver android:name="com.paradroid.paradroidalarm.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.appflood.AFPanelActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appflood.AFFullScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.appflood.notification.NotificationActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appflood.AFListActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appflood.AFInterstitialActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
    </activity>

    <!-- gcm service and receiver -->

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

style.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>
<!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.





-->


<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="dialog_theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#89C2F6</item>
</style>
```

mainmenu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/add_alarm"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_alarm"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_alarm_title"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu" >
</item>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that some Activities use different themes. All Activities where you want an ActionBar must be extended by Theme.Sherlock.

Comment: that's a good point : unfortunately the problem appears on my .MainActivity which has the theme of the application which is a style extending Theme.Sherlock.Light. I tried anyway to apply the sherlock theme to the activity, not working